# Bake every table in CakePHP?

Tags: php, hibernate, cakephp, orm, cakephp-bake

The database I'm working on has more than 100 tables, so I'm not going to sit here baking a model and controller for each one individually. I would like to bake all of the tables at the same time with something like the .xml files in Hibernate that tells it the limitations on fields so that I don't have to go through every column on every table, and automatically select the relationships. Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To bake all of you models, use `cake bake model all`.

Controllers would be `cake bake controller all`

[For Reference](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html)

Comment: Thanks! I was trying `cake bake all` and it was still asking me to select my table. Is there any way to have configuration for each table in regards to fields and relationships?

Comment: The bake will attempt to discover the relationships, primary keys and field validation and create them for you. I'm not sure that there is a way to manually specify those things when you are baking all models at once. If you bake them one at a time, I know you are presented with options.

Answer (score 2):

```
.\console\cake bake model all
```

In your app folder if you haven't yet set the path to cake.